# Can I overlap two framebuffer attachments outputs in a fragment shader?

Tags: vulkan

Right now I am writing out to a colour buffer in the fragment shader, which is a float format.

```
layout (location = 0) out vec4 outColour;
```

I need to have a way to write the object's id to a framebuffer for picking. There are a number of ways I've thought about doing this. I can compile two versions for each shader, one a normal one, and another for the picking, which basically only needs to do the vertex position transformations and then skip everything else, lighting calculations, texturing, etc. This probably isn't ideal because this is essentially doubling the number of shaders I have to write.

An easier method I've thought is to do a conditional branch (preferably over a specialisation constant), and for picking purposes compile a picking version of the graphics pipeline with the picking boolean value set to true. This sounds better. For the ordinary passes I can write to multiple attachments. Will it be best to compile that picking pipeline with a new render pass that writes to only one framebuffer attachment, an integer one? If I swap the render pass for one that writes an integer at attachment 0 instead of the float 4 can I alias this in the fragment shader?

```
layout (location = 0) out vec4 outColour;
layout (location = 0) out ivec4 out_id;

void main()
{
    vec4 colour;
    int object_id;
    if (bPicking)
        out_id = ivec4(object_id, 0, 0, 0); // y, z, w not used
    else
        out_colour = colour;
}
```

I'm guessing I really need a different render pass because instead of writing to a R32G32B32A32_SFLOAT image I'm writing to a R8_UINT image for the IDs. This is really confusing what's the best way to do this?

Comment: The format of the various attachments is baked into a render pass (necessary for optimizations on TBRs), so you're going to have to have two render passes anyway.

Comment: @NicolBolas How is this problem approached? Imagine having a separate shader combination every time. In other words I write a new special effects shader that displaces the vertices in the vertex shader, and then I need to write another one that just does the displacement but not the lighting etc.

Comment: Why not just use MRT and emit both attachments from the same shader instance?

Comment: @solidpixel 
That would mean the framebuffer would always need to have the picking buffer attachment, whether the shader was writing to it or not. So you'd need to allocate an image of that size and attach it to the framebuffer no matter what for any framebuffer you create?

Comment: Sure, but presumably you have it allocated up front anyway - you don't want to be allocating textures at runtime.

Comment: @solidpixel What will happen when the render pass it's writing to a integer attachment at location = 0; but in the shader it says out vec4 outColour; ?? That's supposed to be writing to a float attachment.

Comment: Don't do a separate picking pass - that involves processing positions twice. Use MRT so you compute both color and object ID in a single pass. Color is always in attachment location 0, picking buffer in attachment location 1.  In frames where you don't need picking just use glDrawBuffers to disable the picking attachment.

Comment: @solidpixel glDrawBuffers is a Vulkan feature? That's OpenGl isn't it?

Comment: Not checked, but I assume the same behaviour is possible given that the hardware is the same.